# Fixed values on sorted column with formatted dates

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I have a table initialised by

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD MMM Y' );
})
```

The problem is that my column has both dates and text (only one type of text), i.e. 'ongoing'. The dates have this format: 30 Oct 2020, and I am able to order it correctly thanks to the addition of the `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD MMM Y' );` line. If there's only one instance of 'ongoing' among the data, though, the ordering gets messed up and doesn't work. How can I add an exception to the ordering?

I'm looking for something like

```
"order": [[ 2, "asc" ]], "exception": ["ongoing"]
```

(very pseudo-code).

**Update**

I've learned about the [absoluteOrder](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/absolute) plugin and have implemented like so:

```
  var deadlineType = $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrder( [
    { value: 'ongoing', position: 'top' }
  ] );

"columnDefs": [ {
[...]
{ "targets": 2, type: deadlineType } ]
  })
```

It *almost* works. It puts the 'ongoing' on top. Nevertheless, the data sorting is messed up again, even when using absoluteOrderNumber. Is there an absoluteOrder line specific for dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kthorngren on the [datatables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/181810) I have solved this problem.
This is the working code:

```
    {
      "targets": 2,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        if ( type === 'sort' ) {
          if (data === 'ongoing') {
            return '01 Jan 0001';
          }
          return data;
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
```